# How to update values in dictionary using "if" statements from a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I am working on a supply/demand table that calculates the storage of every point each month. If the storage capacity exceeds 92 at one point, the storage is emptied and the 92 units are "transported" to another point. Afterwards the storage capacity at that point is again 0 and it starts accumulating units. In my case i want to store the 92 units that are "transported away" in a dictionary.

I have written a code for a Excel sheet (which works fine) but now I want to work with a Dataframe instead. However I do not manage to properly update the values in my dictionary with the Dataframe.

I have tried this:

```
#Dictionary
WWTP = {'Mar':0,'Apr':0,'Mai':0,...., 'Feb':0}

for row in df.iteritems():
df['Mar']= df['Supply_month']+ 30
for key, value in WWTP.iteritems():
    if [df.Mar >= 92]:
        WWTP['Mar']=+92
....(more code)
```

The result I get is this.

```
WWTP = {'Mar':92,'Apr':92,'Mai':92,...., 'Feb':92}
```

This only adds 1 time 92 to the dictionary, however I want that it adds 92 every time the value in one row exceeds 92. The results I would like to have is

```
WWTP={'Mar': 92, 'Apr': 184, 'Mai': 1012,...,'Feb':2000}
```

This is the code what I have at the moment, in which the dictionary updates, but not correctly as I want:

```
WWTP = {'Mar':0,'Apr':0,'Mai':0,...., 'Feb':0}

for row in df.iteritems():           
    df['Apr']= df['Mar']+df['Supply_month']
    if [df.Apr >= 92]:
         WWTP['Apr']+=92
         df['Apr']=df['Supply_month']
    else:
         WWTP['Apr']+=0
(...)
```

The result I get :

```
  WWTP={'Mar': 1350, 'Apr': 1350, 'Mai': 1350,...,'Feb':1350}
```

Comment: `WWTP['Mar']=+92 ` should not this be `WWTP['Mar']+=92`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably a little mistake, you need to `WWTP['Mar'] += 92` instead of `WWTP['Mar']=+92`

Comment: oh true! what a stupid mistake. Now it works, thanks :)

Comment: actually I have another question...the dictionary updates now but not as I want it, since the values are same for all keys in the dictionary. ( WWTP = {'Mar':1350,'Apr':1350,...., 'Feb':1350} ). What can still go wrong? I should get the result that I showed above

Comment: You should show the revelant part of the code for this, but things that can go wrong are an incorrect if else, I do not see any other possibilities :). Try to print something inside if to debug and show in which part the code go through

Comment: yes you are right there must be something wrong in the if statement. However I am not able to detect it myself, since I am new in working with Dataframes. I have included the code I have at the moment to the bottom of my question. Maybe you can tell me quickly what exactly is wrong. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Be careful when you are assigning data to your dataframe, `df['Apr']=df['Supply_month']` means every value of df['Apr'] will be equal to the value in df['Supply_month]. This should not be in an iteration :)